# Fourier transform of $H(-t)e^{5t}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

i have to calculate the Fourier transform in the title. My professor says the result is $\frac{1}{5-2\pi i f}$. I start from $H(t)e^{\alpha t}$, and i calculate the transform $H(t)e^{5t}\rightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi i f - 5}$. Now i must pass to $H(-t)...$ and i decide to apply the rescaling property $u(t/\lambda)=\lambda u(\lambda f)$, with $\lambda=-1$, but i get $\frac{-1}{5-2 \pi i f}$, which is not correct... Where am I wrong?

Comment: For rescaling, it scales with respect to $|\lambda|$, not $\lambda$.  See the time-scaling section of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform).

Comment: You're right! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean to compute the Fourier transform of $H(-t)e^{+5t}$ (with a positive exponent)? Because the Fourier transform of the given function doesn't exist.

Comment: You are right, I provide to edit post

Comment: If I have to add a delay like $H(-t-3)e^{5t}$, I just multiply the transform for $e^{-6\pi i f }$. Am I right?